# Find classes which doesn't reference any other custom classes

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, uml, class-diagram

I have a java package which has around 400 classes.
I want to find base classes. Base classes are those which does not have any reference to any other class( in the same big package) 
Is there anyway?

Comment: You're using both Eclipse and IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you have source files, class files or just UML diagrams? With all the tag-spam it's hard to know what you are asking...

Comment: @John3136  Obviously, he is looking for the instrument in any IDE he uses.

Answer (score -1):

Both main proprietary UML tools (VP and EA) have the utility for creation of class diagrams from the code. But the utilities are in the paid variant only and thus for free you can use them for one month. In the diagrams you can simply see your base classes.

IntelliJIdea has no tools for that. And as for Eclipse, its UML plugins are developing and you should simply search. Maybe, you'll find something really free.